# How to use input text in a href (HTML)

Tags: html, input, href

What I want to do is have an input and then refer to that input in an href, I am a total HTML noob so I don't even know if this is possible but something like this:

```
<input type="search" id="Searchbar">
<a href = "/user/"+Searchbar><button>Search<button></a>
```

Is it possible to do something like this or similar?

Comment: is necessary use of Javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is necessary use of Javascript to complement part of this action.

Note the tag "input" is "Self-Closing Tag" "/"

```
<input type="search" id="searchbar" value="type here"/>
<button id="goto">Search</button>
```

In your script Javascript add this:

```
document.getElementById("goto").addEventListener("click", goTo);

function goTo() {  
  var result = document.getElementById("searchbar").value;  
  window.location.href = '/user/'+result;
}
```

My example:
https://codepen.io/dieterich/pen/MWKyLOE

Comment: Excuse me, I am not very familiar with JavaScript, I implemented it like this:
`<script language="JavaScript">Your code</script>`
Right after the `</body>` tag and can't understand why this is not working, do you mind taking the time to correct me if I did something wrong? 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi! do not use tag script after, only before </body>, and this then work fine. I have updated the example, check now. If this answer is useful, please accept this answer with solved. Thanks a lot!